# Does rake task limit functionality of my class to call external API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

AllegroAPI is a class in the /models directory that calls an external API. It works as I wish when I test in somewhere else not by running rake task.

Example working code:

```
require "./AllegroAPI"

allegro = AllegroAPI.new(login: 'LOGIN', 
                      password: File.read('XXXX.txt'),
                      webapikey: File.read('XXX.txt')
                    )
puts allegro.do_search({"search-string"=>"nokia", 
                        "search-price-from"=>300.0, 
                        "search-price-to"=>500.0, 
                        "search-limit"=>50}).to_s
```

As I've said it works correctly. It calls the API and prints out the result.

File allegro.rb is also in the models directory and it's a file I'm executing by running this task:

```
namespace :data do
  desc "Update auctions table in database"
  task update_auctions: :environment do
    Allegro.check_for_new_auctions
  end
end
```

allegro.rb:

```
module Allegro
  require 'AllegroAPI'
  def self.check_for_new_auctions
    allegro = AllegroAPI.new(login: 'LOGIN', 
                      password: File.read('app/models/ignore/XXXX.txt'),
                      webapikey: File.read('app/models/ignore/XXX.txt')
                    )
    looks = Look.all
    looks.each do |l|
      hash_to_ask = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(l[:look_query]).symbolize_keys
      hash_to_ask = hash_to_ask.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v), h|
        if v.is_number?
          h[k.to_s.split('_').join('-')] = v.to_f
        else
          h[k.to_s.split('_').join('-')] = v 
        end
      end
      results = allegro.do_search(hash_to_ask)
      #do something with data 
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that it doesn't return anything. var result is not nil, but it does not hold anything.

When I'm trying to debug it and call API from the inside do_search function it's calling API, doesn't raise a error but response is nothing. AllegroAPI works correctly. There is no problem with var "hash_to_ask", it's exactly the same hash as in working example.

EDIT:

I've commented out check_for_new_auctions and used "puts", it works fine when I run it by executing rake task. Then I've used exactly the same code which I used in normal file which have ran properly:

```
class Allegro
  def self.check_for_new_auctions
    allegro = AllegroAPI.new(login: 'LOGIN', 
                      password: File.read('app/models/ignore/XXXX.txt'),
                      webapikey: File.read('app/models/ignore/XXXX.txt')
                    )
    hash_to_ask = {"search-string"=>"nokia", 
                   "search-price-from"=>300.0, 
                   "search-price-to"=>500.0, 
                   "search-limit"=>50}
    allegro.do_search(hash_to_ask).to_s
  end
end
```

It have not worked;/ The returned value from allegro.do_search(hash_to_ask) is hash, not empty, not nil but when I try to print it, it's nothing, empty place.

EDIT:

Everything have worked properly, waste like 15 hours total debugging the problem which have not existed. I'm not sure why it have not worked but it couldn't print to the console after converting to string, so I tried writing it down to file blindly. What I have found in the text file? Data. 
I don't know why it couldn't print out everything in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the IRB script that you show, you have some puts statement that is not in your rake task. So for debugging, I would add puts ... to your Rake task, e.g.:

```
namespace :data do
  desc "Update auctions table in database"
  task update_auctions: :environment do
    puts "Start Auctions..."
    results = Allegro.check_for_new_auctions
    puts "Results: #{results}"
  end
end
```

Now, when you run:

```
rake data:update_auctions
```

You should get some output. Otherwise rinse-and-repeat by adding puts statements in the method that you are calling.

Comment: I've debugged whole file AllegroAPI, when I'm running it by rake the response is empty, not nil. When I run it by hand not by rake everything works.

Comment: can you replace everything in the check_new_auctions block with "test value" and see if the "test value" is printed in the rake task? I've done a small test myself and the task ... do ... end block should read the value from your module just fine... I suspect there is an error in your block def check_new_auctions ... end

Comment: I've edited my question and solved the problem! Thank you for help.